# Docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have the following issue when I run the command `docker run -v $(pwd):opt -p 8080:8080 -it synedra/hapi_api`:

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
>   '/home/joasimar/trai/new:opt': invalid mount config for type "bind":
>   invalid mount path: 'opt' mount path must be absolute.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to set an absolute path for the destination directory when using volumes. BTW read [the documentations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) comprehensively  before posting a question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The paths have to be absolute. There is no current working directory or `/` assumed. Change it to:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/opt -p 8080:8080 -it synedra/hapi_api
```

Comment: This is Oct. 2021 and all I can say is: thanks so much. You saved me sleepless nights

Comment: does it give the same error if you use `~/` as the start of your route?